# Creating MPEG4 video file with Python from raw frames

Tags: python, video, encoding, ffmpeg, mpeg-4

I have a raw video frame source which I can access in Python. I'd like to create a MPEG4 video out of this, with MP3 background music.

What kind of tools and libraries are available in Python for such a task? Preferably I'd like to have an API for which I can feed output filename and then individual frames as 24 bit raw images.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenCV and the corresponding Python binding, you could use something like the function `cv.WriteFrame`.  You could also use pyffmpeg, but that is geared more towards accessing individual frames from a video file.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should be able to do what you requesting:

- http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/
- http://code.google.com/p/wffmpeg/
- http://pymedia.org/

Comment: pymedia: dead, pyffmpeg: read only, wffmpeg: command line wrapper. No dice, but thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Because this question still shows up pretty high in relevant Google searches, here's the library I'm using now:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpy/0.0.4

It is lightweight and still works.

Per Neal, OpenCV has the best libraries for editing, but does not (AFAIK) support MPEG.